# Combine dataframes by shared key without broadcasting rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two DataFrames df1 and df2
Each df has the following structure: an id, and other variables

```
df1
id  var1   var2
100  1      blue
100  2      orange
101  3      red
102  1      apple

df2
id  var3   var4
99   2      purple
100  3      pineaple
100  4      banana
100  15     pumpkin
70   1      juice
```

Some keys are common to both DataFrames. I need to combine them to obtain something like this:

```
id  var1   var2     var3     var4
99   none   none     2      purple
100  1      blue     3      pineaple
100  2      orange   4      banana
100  none   none     15     pumpkin
101  3      red      none   none
102  1      apple    none   none
70   none   none     1      juice
```

This is, to combine info on common indexes. I tried joins and merges but I always obtain a "broadcasted" version of the table. Given common indexes on both tables, pandas repeats every row of the first DataFrame for each row of the second one. It looks like this:

```
id  var1   var2     var3     var4
99   none   none     2      purple
100  1      blue     3      pineaple
100  1      blue     4      banana
100  1      blue     15     pumpkin
100  2      orange   3      pineaple
100  2      orange   4      banana
100  2      orange   15     pumpkin
101  3      red      none   none
102  1      apple    none   none
70   none   none     1      juice
```

What can I try in order to get what i need?
Thanks in advance

Some more info
I have two teams working on maintenance plans for an industrial plant. Each one of them gave me a supply order containing parts that the plant has to buy. I want to compare their plans, to find differences on their supply orders given common plans. Additionaly, one  may be working on a plan that the other team is not.

Comment: Perhaps `pd.concat`?

Comment: pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)

Comment: In your example, how do you know which row with id = 100 in df2 aligns with which id = 100 in df1? If it's just the order (1,blue lines up with 3, pineapple because they are the first id = 100 row in each df), then you can add a column in each df that says which instance of the id that the current row is for the id then you can use both columns in your join

Comment: I'm guessing var1 and var3 are unit counts for what is in var2 and var4 in which case you would want to sum each table individually first so that you have a one to one relationship between rows. Then you can join the datasets together.